# Show/hide (fade in/out) several DIVS inside table row with several A HREF in other row and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okey, so this is what I’m looking for…

I have 3 links (*a href*'s) in 3 columns in 1 row. Below is 1 column in one row with 3 *divs* in it. 
**How do I make the *divs* fade in/fade out (as stated below) if the links are clicked?**

- From beginning all *#info...*’s are hidden.
- If *Link 1* is clicked *#info-first* fades in. If then *Link 2* is clicked *#info-first*
  fades away and *#info-second* fades in and so on for all *Link*'s.
- Also there is a hide option for all the *#info-...*’s so it goes back to what it was in the beginning (all hidden).

Simpel demonstration: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7MEh/1/)**

### UPDATE: SOLUTION

Thank you Eduardo (he commented final solution): See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/C7MEh/8/)**.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="banner-content-wrap">
<div class="banner-text"><span>Cool</span> slogan goes here. <span>Cool</span> indeed.
    <br/>
    <div id="explain">From beginning all #info... is hidden. If Link 1 is clicked #info-first fades in. If then Link 2 is clicked #info-first
        <br/>fades away and #info-second fades in and so on. Also there is a hide option for all the #info-...</div>
    <div class="banner-links">
        <table border="1">
            <tr class="first">
                <td class="first">about</td>
                <td class="second">about</td>
                <td class="third">about</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="second">
                <td class="first"><a href="#">LINK 1</a>

                </td>
                <td class="second"><a href="#">LINK 2</a>

                </td>
                <td class="third"><a href="#">LINK 3</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="third">
                <td colspan="3">
                    <div id="info">
                        <div class="info-first">Link 1 fades in #info-first info
                            <br/>
                            <br/><a href="#">HIDE #info-first</a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="info-second">Link 2 fades in #info-second text
                            <br/>
                            <br/><a href="#">HIDE #info-second</a>

                        </div>
                        <div class="info-third">Link 3 fades in #info-third text
                            <br/>
                            <br/><a href="#">HIDE #info-third</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#banner-content-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 960px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -480px;
}
#explain {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
}
.banner-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 950px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family:'Berlin Sans FB';
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}
.banner-text span {
    color: #000;
}
.banner-links table {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.banner-links tr.first td.first {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.banner-links tr.first td.second {
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-links tr.first td.third {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.banner-links tr.first {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    opacity: 0.75;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.first {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.second {
    text-align: center;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.third {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.banner-links tr.second {
line-height: 24px;
}
.banner-links tr.second a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
    opacity: 0.75;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.banner-links tr.second a:hover {
    opacity: 0.95;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.first a:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.second a:hover {
color: #34b700;
}
.banner-links tr.second td.third a:hover {
    color: #004eb7;
}
.banner-links tr.third td {
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
.banner-links #info {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:'Verdana';
    text-align: left;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
}
.banner-links .info-first {
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.banner-links .info-second {
    background: #34b700;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.banner-links .info-third {
    background: #004eb7;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to use just css for [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo).

Comment: @user3334690 other than :checked, :hover etc, css does not have a click selector yet, i'm curious how we can do this using pure css?

Comment: @TilwinJoy if you change the anchor tags with "#" to target a named element you could get the current target with a css selector and exclude it from those being hidden?  I don't think the target selector works in jsfiddle though... and looking back I'm not sure it would satisfy what OP was looking for... but I think it is possible...

Comment: @TilwinJoy I googled it and found [this](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-target/accordionvert.html), which is a pretty slick accordion, using only css (via the :target selector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fadeToggle()` will do the trick 
Also using css to hide the elements with *info-(something)*

```
$(".second td").click(function(){
   $(".info-"+$(this).attr("class")).fadeToggle()
});
```

Depending on the `td` clicked on `.second` we will create the selector for the `divs` and then we call `fadeToggle()` to hide them or to show them depending on their current visibility.

```
div[class^='info-']{
    display:none;
 }
```

To hide the divs this select any div with a class that starts with "info-"

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/C7MEh/5/)

Comment: Very nice! Though, is it possbile to get is so whenever a Link is clicked the one that is currently showing fades away? I just want to have one of them visible at a time. Cheers!

Comment: Very good, thank you! I don't mean to be picky, but it seems like when clicking another Link the previous one is visible for a short time as well. Is it possible to make the first one fade away then AFTER the new one fades in?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/C7MEh/7/ This will wait for the toggleFade() to finish and then it will hide the other elements.

Comment: I'm so sorry, haha. English isn't my native language. I didn't explained it how I meant it. Sorry. I meant the other way around. Fade away first, then fade in the other.

Comment: Lol np just exchange the selectors like this http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/C7MEh/8/